# Trouble passing object over as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having trouble passing an object over as props. I have a click event where I create an object from function parameters:

```
addClass: function(c){
   var details =  [{
        course: c.name, 
        credits: c.credits,
        time: c.time,
        days: c.days,
        enrolled: true
    }]

   this.setState({schedule: this.state.schedule.concat(details)})
},
```

And I am trying to map over the array in my `Schedule` component like this:

```
var schedule = this.props.schedule.map(function(index, s){
        return (<li key={index}>{s.time}</li>)
    })

    return (
        <div className="schedule">
        <h4>Your Fall semester schedule</h4>
            <ul>
                {schedule}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
```

For some reason I am unable to display any of the `details` properties in my `Schedule` component. Here is a demo:http://codepen.io/p-adams/pen/qNxZBV
Basically want I am trying to do is display the course name, time, and days in `Schedule` component each time the `add` button is pressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reversing the arguments of your `.map` function.

Change this:

```
this.props.schedule.map(function(index, s){
```

To be this:

```
this.props.schedule.map(function(s, index){
```